# python mysqlx.Result.get_autoincrement_value() doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-8.0, document-storage

I'm trying to use the document storage of MySQL 8 in my python project(python 3.8). The version of MySQL-connector python is 8.0.20. According to the [API reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/mysqlx.Result.html) and the [X DevAPI User Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/working-with-document-ids.html), I tried to get the auto increment document ID after adding a document into the DB. Each time after the execution, the data would be inserted into DB successfully, but '-1' would be returned after get_autoincrement_value() was invoked.

My code is just like below:

```
    try:
        schema = session.get_schema('my_schema')
        collection = schema.get_collection('my_collection')
        topic_dict = protobuf_to_dict(topic)
        doc_id = collection.add(topic_dict).execute().get_autoincrement_value()
        logger.debug('doc_id: {}', doc_id)
        return doc_id
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("failed to add topic to db, topic: {}, err: {}", topic, e)
```

Is there anything wrong with my usage? Thank you all~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are interested in the document id that has been auto-generated. If that is the case, you should instead use [`get_generated_ids`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/mysqlx.Result.html#mysqlx.Result.get_generated_ids):

```
doc_id = collection.add(topic_dict).execute().get_generated_ids()[0]
```

In this case, the method returns a list of all the ids that were generated in the scope of the `add()` operation.

The documentation is probably not clear enough, but `get_auto_increment_value()` only contains useful data if you are inserting a row with either [`session.sql()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/mysqlx.Session.html#mysqlx.Session.sql) or [`table.insert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/mysqlx.Table.html#mysqlx.Table.insert) on a table containing an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column. It has no meaning in the scope of NoSQL collections because in the end a collection is just a table created like (condensed version):

```
CREATE TABLE collection (
  `doc` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `_id` varbinary(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
)
```

Which means there isn't anything to "auto increment".

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help~ So excited to get an answer from one of the core developers of MySQL connectors~ :)  Yes, I'm trying to extract the document ID for some other use. It's the first time for me to try MySQL document storage. I will try to get more knowledge on the usage to avoid such silly questions.  I have tried your suggestion and it works well~ :)  Again, than you so much~